# Using sed/awk to grab text between an anchor (that can repeat) and not the anchor

Tags: awk, sed

Any thoughts on how to get just the content between `--AnchorABC` and `--Anchor<not ABC>` when `--AnchorABC` can repeat 1-n times?

Example input:

```
It
is
a
lovely
day
--AnchorABC something
--AnchorABC something else
--AnchorABC yet something else
Hey
how 
are
you
--AnchorXYZ
I 
am
fine
--AnchorLMN
```

Example output (having the last line deleted isn't super important):

```
--AnchorABC something
--AnchorABC something else
--AnchorABC yet something else
Hey
how 
are
you
--AnchorXYZ
```

If there are an even number of `--AnchorABC` then it is easy (albeit hacky), but is there is an odd number, then the hack breaks down.  With sed, I was trying to do a pattern range between `--AnchorABC` and a line that starts with `--` but does *not* have AnchorABC, but sed doesn't have negative lookahead.

Basically the problem statement is: print all lines between the first occurrence of a pattern that starts with `--` and has a key after `--` and then an arbitrary ending and the next occurrence of a line that starts with the pattern `--` but with a different key.  Or another way:

- match `--AnchorABC`

  - if subsequent lines match `--AnchorABC` or anything that does not start with `--`, print it
  - if a line matches `--Anchor` but it is not `--AnchorABC`, stop

EDITS: make it clear that the 2nd anchor key is not known and that the 'key' can be multiple characters.

Comment: Did you try `sed '/--AnchorA/,/--AnchorB/!d' infile`? Once the first address has been seen, it is ignored until the second is seen.

Comment: Sorry 'AnchorB' is not known explicitly (it could be Anchor[a-zA-z0-9]+)  So basically we need to do between `--AnchorA` and *not* `--AnchorA`.  I will update question to make that clear.

Comment: `sed '/--AnchorA/,/--Anchor[^A]/!d' infile` then.

Comment: I'm asking in a comment instead of answering because you say you tried a sed pattern range - have you tried something other than this?

Comment: Editing the question in a way that invalidates existing answers is poor form, by the way.

Comment: @BenjaminW I know, I'm not proud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '/^--/{f=/--AnchorABC/} f' file
--AnchorABC something
--AnchorABC something else
--AnchorABC yet something else
Hey
how
are
you
```

It could be tweaked to print the terminating non-matching line too but you said `having the last line deleted isn't super important` so I didn't bother.

Explanation:

1. `/^--/{f=/--AnchorABC/}` = when the current line starts with `--` it sets a flag `f` to `1` if that line contains `--AnchorABC` and `0` otherwise.
2. `f` on it's own at the end = If the flag `f` is set to `1` then awks
   default action occurs which is to print the current line.

Comment: If you don’t mind adding explanation as to how it works, I’d appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '/^--AnchorA/{l=1} /^--Anchor[^A]/{l=0; print; exit}l' file.txt
```

Or simpler, thanks @iamuser for the idea :

```
awk '/^--AnchorA/{l=1}; l; /^--Anchor[^A]/{exit}' file.txt
```

### Explanations:

- `//{}` = regex condition and execution
- so `/^--AnchorA/{l=1}` means assign `l=1` if regex match
- the `l` in the middle is an awk trick: it means `true`, and on a true condition, awk default is to print.
- same thing for the second `//{}`, but we use a negative range to exclude character `A`
  When l=1 awk print on STDOUT, when l=0 it doesn't

### If you need to negate not a character but a string

then [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) comes to the rescue with *look around* regex advanced technic :

```
perl -ne 'print if /^--AnchorA/ .. /^--Anchor(?!A)/' file.txt
```

Check [look around](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) (You can replace `A` by a string, not just a character)

### Or keeping [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '
    /^--AnchorA/{l=1;print;next};
    l;
    /^--Anchor/ && $0 !~ /^--AnchorABC/ {exit}
' file.txt
```

Comment: What if the anchor 'key' was multiple characters?  The `[^A]` is a regex character class.

Comment: All characters excepted A

Comment: That's exactly what you asked in your original post.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, your solution works as the original question was raised.  I realized that assuming a fixed single character as the key to the anchor is not what I'm trying to solve (I over simplified it).  That's why negative lookahead would be handy but I don't want to pull perl/ruby into the solution :).

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it out in sed and it is ugly :). That awk solution is at lease understandable.

Comment: `awk '/^--Anchor/ { anchor=$1 } anchor=="--AnchorABC"'`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a nasty [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution though I prefer Gilles' [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution for readability:

```
sed -ne "/^--AnchorA/{p;                                                                                         
                      :loop
                      n;
                      p;
                      /^--/{/^--AnchorA/\!q};
                      b loop}" testfile | sed '$d'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^--AnchorABC/{:a;N;/^--AnchorABC[^\n]*\'\''/Mba;/^--Anchor[^\n]*\'\''/M!ba;p}' file
```

Used GNU seds multiline end-of-string `\'` (shown here as `\'\''` because the command is single quoted). This uses the `N` to gather up multiple lines, if the last line appended is `--AnchorABC` continue appending until a line that begins `--Anchor` and does not continue  `ABC` then print the collection and repeat.

N.B. Seds `M` flag allows `^` and `\'` to match the start of a line and the end of the pattern space respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution,

```
 $ awk '/AnchorA/{a=1};a;/AnchorB/{exit}' file
```

and here is a `sed` solution,

```
$ sed '/AnchorA/,/AnchorB/!d;/AnchorB/q' file
```

Output  (in both case):

```
--AnchorA something
--AnchorA something else
--AnchorA yet something else
Hey
how 
are
you
--AnchorB
```

Comment: OP said that AnchorB is not fixed.

Comment: Sorry, `--AnchorB` is not a constant I know, I updated the question to make that clear.  I just know a line will come that is `--Anchor<not A>`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v search="AnchorABC" '
                           BEGIN{r="^[-]+"search}
                           $0~r{f=1}f;
                           /^[-]+/ && $0 !~ r{exit}
                          ' file
```

Test Results:

***Input:***

```
$ cat file
It
is
a
lovely
day
--AnchorABC something
--AnchorABC something else
--AnchorABC yet something else
Hey
how 
are
you
--AnchorXYZ
I 
am
fine
--AnchorLMN
```

*Output:*

```
$ awk -v search="AnchorABC" 'BEGIN{r="^[-]+"search}$0~r{f=1}f;/^[-]+/ && $0 !~ r{exit}' file
--AnchorABC something
--AnchorABC something else
--AnchorABC yet something else
Hey
how 
are
you
--AnchorXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution mixing `grep` and `sed` with **negative lookahead**:

```
$ A=$(grep -Pnm1 '^--AnchorABC' input.file | cut -d':' -f1); B=$(tail -n +$A input.file |grep -Pnm1 '^--Anchor(?!ABC)' | cut -d':' -f1); sed -n "$A,+$((B-1)) p" input.file 
--AnchorABC something
--AnchorABC something else
--AnchorABC yet something else
Hey
how 
are
you
--AnchorXYZ
```

**Explanations:**

1. `$(grep -Pnm1 '^--AnchorABC' input.file | cut -d':' -f1)` find the line number of the first occurrence of `--AnchorABC`
2. `$(tail -n +$A input.file |grep -Pnm1 '^--Anchor(?!ABC)' | cut -d':' -f1)` from that first occurrence you find how many lines until reaching a line that meet the `'^--Anchor(?!ABC)'` condition and you get its line number relatively to the the first occurrence of `'^--AnchorABC'`
3. You print only the range in question with `sed -n "$A,+$((B-1)) p" input.file`